list with item be a link to another page
I am working on a car maintenance app. I have a page for spare parts and a page for purchasing orders.
The purchasing order page form contains a region to insert master data and an interactive grid region to insert the detail of the purchasing order.
The interactive grid contains:
order_id
spare_parts_category
part_code
qty
unit_price_total_price

I want the part_code to be a select list or LOV based on the spare_parts_category column and contain an item named NEW_PART when I clicked on it redirect me to another page to insert new spare part in spare parts table.
I have tried to do that as a LOV based on category table union all new_part as display value and -1 as return value. I also created a javascript dynamic action to open the new page but nothing happened.
this is the LOV code
SELECT 
  PART_NAME AS DISPLAY_VALUE, 
  PART_ID AS RETURN_VALUE
FROM 
  SPARE_PARTS
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      'New Part' AS DISPLAY_VALUE, 
      -1 AS RETURN_VALUE
    FROM 
      DUAL
    ORDER BY DISPLAY_VALUE; 

if (this.triggeringElement.value == '-1') {
  apex.navigation.dialog({
    url: 'f?p=&APP_ID.:<13>:&SESSION.::NO:::'
  });
}

Can anyone help me to do that?

Does the SQL actually return a list of new parts?
And where is the JS part triggered? Can you share a bit more code please?

If I were you, I'd create a separate button on that page whose label would be "Enter new part(s)" that redirects to a new page which is used to enter parts that are missing.
